# Trouble with connection to PostgreSQL server on VPS Server

Tags: networking, server, postgresql

I'm trying to configure a database on my personal VPS server on Veesp, but it just doesn't work whatever I do. I configured both of [pg_nba.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwt96.png) and [postgresql.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSjXi.png) files, so I can connect from anywhere. But all I get is this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFdUC.png).

Here is `ss -tunelp |grep 5433` output:

```
tcp     LISTEN   0        244            127.0.0.1:5433           0.0.0.0:*      users: 
(("postgres",pid=1290,fd=6)) uid:113 ino:28085 sk:8 <->
tcp     LISTEN   0        244                [::1]:5433              [::]:*      users: 
(("postgres",pid=1290,fd=5)) uid:113 ino:28084 sk:9 v6only:1 <->
```

What have I missed? Maybe there is another issue causing this? I rebooted service many times, open port 5433 by this command:

```
sudo ufw allow 5433/tcp
```

But still no effect. Server runs on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the `listen_addresses` was commented by default somehow. Uncommenting were fixed the problem.

**Before:**

```
# - Connection Settings -
# listen_addresses = '*'
```

**After:**

```
# - Connection Settings -
listen_addresses = '*'
```